# How can I limit the number of things Yolov7 can Identify?

Tags: object-detection, object-recognition, object-tracking

So Yolov7/v8 are able to classify numerous distinct objects. One of those objects is cups for example. If I wanted to only look of cups how would I change my setup without having to do custom object identification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's straightforward in theory, although in practice might depend on your codebase. There is a classification head or network that takes the bounding boxes and gives you class probabilities (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/3b41c2cc709628a8c1966931e696b14c11d6db0c/utils/general.py#L876)). What you do is to keep the bounding boxes with high class probability on the class you're interested in. If you want to detect cups, you need to find what's the cups class and then filter according to that class (e.g. `pred_cls2 == 5` if `5` is the "cups" index).